# What's the difference between these two memory allocations?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, buffer

What's the difference between `char str[10]` and `char *str = (char *) malloc(10)`? As I understand, don't both of them allocate 10 bytes for an array of `char`s?

Comment: If `char str[10]` is used outside a function, it is a global variable. The memory is allocated by the compiler and becomes (probably) part of your binary (as it is initialized). If `char str[10]` is used inside a function, it is allocated on _stack_ each time the function is entered (and released on return). `char *str = (char *) malloc(10)` allocates the memory in the _heap_. You are responsible to release it (using `free()`). Otherwise it is called a leak, once you re-assign `str` with another address (i.e. the allocated memory gets "lost" until end of program).

Comment: If you didn't find it in your C book, throw it away and buy a good one... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `char str[10];`

Global (static) scope - allocated in the `.data` or `.bss` segments (depending on the initialisation. Cannot be freed before program termination.

Local (automatic) scope - usually (most implementations but C standard does not defie anything like the "stack") allocated on the stack. Automatically freed when program leaves the scope.

2.

`char *str = malloc(10);`

Allocated on heap. Needs to be freed by the program using the `free` function

Answer (score -1):

`char str[10]` allocate memory on stack. `char *str = (char *) malloc(10)` allocate memory on heap. Stack and Heap stored in the computer's RAM. [More information about stack and heap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79936/8873191).

Comment: wrong: `Stack is used for static memory allocation` it is not